# How can I generate friendly URL from the below URL in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Here is my old style url

> http://djit.ac/djitblog/?controller=blog&action=view&id=4

How can I make it to look like this?

> http://djit.ac/djitblog/blog/view/4

So far I've tried this, but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^blog/view/([0-9]+)/?$    ?controller=blog&action=view&id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Comment: I think those 2 have different meaning.Or maybe it is just me

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Please share what you have tried.